# Ошибка module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'get_map'

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, jupyter-notebook

При построении графика возникла ошибка, что в модуле pyplot нет get_map.
Код:

```
df.plot(kind="scatter", x="longitude", y="latitude", alpha=0.4,
       s=df["population"]/100, label="population",figsize=(10,7),
       c="median_house_value", cmap=plt.get_map("jet"), colorbar=True,
)
plt.legend()
```

Ошибка:

```
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'get_map'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно сначала имопртировать

```
from matplotlib import cm
```

а потом, вместо,

```
cmap=plt.get_map("jet")
```

использовать

```
cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap("jet")
```

Comment: получилось, большое спасибо!